# ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have an error on my spec test and I don't know how to fix it:

```
An error occurred in an after hook
  ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show", :name=>#<User id: 1, email: "testspec@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$z8LP2/rW7vhP9lYQ2bSrCeZ5ASYG2O8XUgRwI3/1R2aJ...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2013-05-01 17:21:03", last_sign_in_at: "2013-05-01 17:21:03", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2013-05-01 17:20:59", updated_at: "2013-05-01 17:21:03", name: nil, role: "user">}
  occurred at /Users/ejiqpep/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:533:in `raise_routing_error'
```

My test is:

```
 before(:each) do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    login_as(user, :scope => :user)
  end
  it "shouldn't allow user to delete last ingredient field", :js => true do
    visit new_recipe_path
    current_path.should == new_recipe_path
    click_link('Remove')
    page.should have_css('.ingredients-form')
  end
```

The problem is in my layout page. When I comment this line all works. But on my own I can click that link and get an error only in tests.

```
= link_to current_user.email, current_user, :class => 'btn'
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_name(params[:id])
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
EcookRails::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  devise_scope :user do
    get '/login' => 'devise/sessions#new'
    post '/login' => 'devise/sessions#create'
    get '/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    get '/register' => 'devise/registrations#new'
  end
  resources :recipes
  resources :users

  match 'favorites/:recipe_id' => 'favorites#create', :as => :favorite
  root :to => 'recipes#index'

end
```

i think the problem can be in my user loggining in rspec. I use the Devise method to authorize in capybara.

my rake routes output:

```
 new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)       devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)   devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)  devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)         devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)        devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)           devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#destroy
                   login GET    /login(.:format)                devise/sessions#new
                         POST   /login(.:format)                devise/sessions#create
                  logout GET    /logout(.:format)               devise/sessions#destroy
                register GET    /register(.:format)             devise/registrations#new
                 recipes GET    /recipes(.:format)              recipes#index
                         POST   /recipes(.:format)              recipes#create
              new_recipe GET    /recipes/new(.:format)          recipes#new
             edit_recipe GET    /recipes/:id/edit(.:format)     recipes#edit
                  recipe GET    /recipes/:id(.:format)          recipes#show
                         PUT    /recipes/:id(.:format)          recipes#update
                         DELETE /recipes/:id(.:format)          recipes#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)            users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)       users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)            users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)            users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)            users#destroy
                favorite        /favorites/:recipe_id(.:format) favorites#create
                    root        /                               recipes#index
```

Comment: Can we see your routes file?

Comment: In you test, did you sign in the user? Otherwise, if in your app in order to access that link you need to be logged in, it's not going to be able to find that route.

Comment: i've updated my test also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have the following part in your RSpec configuration, add it and see if that was the problem.

```
config.before(:each, js: true) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
end
```

Comment: I've added this code to my spec_helper.rb but I still have this error. My code there is :  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)

  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

Comment: Can you post the results of the `rake routes` command? For some reason, the error you get comes while trying to resolve a path with a :name part... By the way, when you create your user via factory, can you assign a non nil value to its name attribute?

Comment: Ok, from this line `user GET    /users/:id(.:format)            users#show`, I understand that the user_path (the one requested by your 'current_user' in the problematic link) needs an :id but instead from your error output it gets a :name variable. We are at a good point :)

Comment: in my user.rb model i has method to param to use name instead of id **def to_param
    name
  end**

Comment: Hmmm, I think that this is the problem... Can you remove this method just to see if that is what causes the problem?

Comment: yes you are right. the problem is there with id all works ok. mb you can recommend me the way to make name in url where my tests also will work?

Comment: Can you try replacing your link with this one: `= link_to current_user.email, user_path(current_user, id: current_user.id), :class => 'btn'`

Comment: i replaced link_to with you advice and i have the same error.